# Fetch data from a text(.txt) file using @Dataprovider annotation (TestNG)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

Usually we use `@dataProvider` for Excel file;  If it is so for a text **(.txt)** file, any examples will be helpful.. Any help is highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason why it won't work. A dataprovider function is like any other function (in terms of how it fetches data, that is). All you have to ensure, is that you return an `Object[][].`
In my situation, I fetch credentials from a .properties file in my `@dataprovider.`

Here's how I do it. You can easily convert it to read from anything:

```
@DataProvider(name="creds")
    protected Object[][] returnCreds() {
        Properties cred = new Properties();
        try {
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "cred.properties");
            cred.load(input);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            ApiHelper.doLog(e.getMessage(),false,ApiHelper.logVerbosity.ERROR);
        }
        Object[][] creds = new Object[1][2];
        creds[0][0] = cred.getProperty("user");
        creds[0][1] = cred.getProperty("pass");
        return creds;
    }

    @Test(dataProvider="creds")
    protected void testCreds(String username, String password) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(username + password);
    }
```

**EDIT**

The above code assumes your properties file has a single entry:

```
user=xyz
pass=123
```

For the case when you have `search=keyword1,keyword2,keyword3` and need to run the search 3 times for each `keyword`, you can simply do some additional processing:

```
String[] splits = cred.getProperty("search").split(",");
```

Now simply store each split keyword into one element of the creds[][] object. Left as an exercise for you :)

Comment: Sure, I too feel the same; There is no such content in internet so far. I will try to come up with this task ASAP.

Comment: @PrashanthSams I edited my answer to add some code. Hope this helps.

Comment: Let me check and get back to you Vish; Thank you for your work

Comment: Hi Vish, it worked for properties file but in my case, [search=keyword1,keyword2,keyword3] I need to run the test 3 times. In the above script the test run only once

Comment: ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("config");
String Channel = bundle.getString("search");
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(Channel, ",");
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
 String value = st.nextToken();
 driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
 driver.findElement(By.id("")).click();
 driver.findElement(By.id("")).sendKeys(value);
}

Comment: The above script usually separates two keywords; how to merge this with dataprovider?

Comment: The information you are requesting is _basically general string processing._ It has nothing to do with `@DataProvider`. I have edited my answer; please use that info and your own research - I'm sure you can figure the rest out.

Comment: Thank you Vish. Tt helps me; Need more improvements in it :)

Answer (score 1):

[This repo](https://github.com/prashanth-sams/dataprovider_text.git) has the live example. please verify.

Comment: Hey @Karthikeyan let me check :)

Comment: it works fine; I feel some improvements to be done; Will check with you shortly

Comment: @PrashanthSams, Updated the code, can you please check

Comment: changes needed here; I feel the same what you say, "google class' has to worked out'
String usernameStrings[]=dataSet.get("username");
        String passwordStrings[]=dataSet.get("password");
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            creds[i][0]=usernameStrings[i];
            creds[i][1]=passwordStrings[i];
        }

Comment: Thank you @karthikeyan for your excellent work ;)